# Find asymptotics of function "n+n/2+n/4..+1 = 2n-1"

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

I need to find asymptotics of the function
$f(n) = 2^k + 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-2} + ... + 2 + 1 = 2n - 1$, When $n$ is $2^k$

I have to find constants $a$ and $b$, so that $f(n) \sim a * n^b$ when
$n \to \infty$

Or if $f(n)$ grows exponentially, I need to find $a$ and $b$, so that
$f(n) \sim a * b^n$

I really can't figure out how to do this, could someone help me out?

Comment: I'm having a hard time making sense of your expression " f(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + n/(n/2) + 1 = 2n - 1". Could you say, for example, how the formula works for $n=7$?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention. This function works when n=2^k. For example 16+8+4+2+1 = 31 or 2*16-1 = 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

It seems to me you're already done.

You've said that $f(n) = 2n - 1$... But this grows like $2n^1$, since

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f}{2n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2n} \to 1$$

So $f$ grows polynomially, with $a = 2$ and $b = 1$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much!